# Access array index by result of calculation

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-1.2

I try to access an array using as index the result of a calculation.

`<tr:outputText value="#{myController.form.model.arr[(status.index / 15)]}"/>`

`status.index` comes from a `tr:iterator` variable `varStatus`.

It seems howewer, that this is a double value internally as I get a `javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string: "0.0"`.

Can I somehow cast this to an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it has been resolved. I had another constellation where a .toString was added by an own method. It works the way it is posted here.